# Environment variable MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK == 1, overriding \"processManagement.fork\" to false"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, backend

I tried convert standalone MongoDB to replica set with only one replica, it was required for change streams on my backend.
I found error, which don't descripted in any site in google, so here is error message: 'Environment variable MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK == 1, overriding "processManagement.fork" to false"'.
Anybody who knows how solve it?

I tried search environment variable in linux -- not found, i tried set variable with descripted name to environment in linux -- not works, and searched possible enviroment variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, and would like to share this solution by infromation in this topic https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-a-systemd-service_598533

here
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
i needed delete string MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK=1

Comment: Forgot, after save file you need in terminal sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: You should not edit file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` directly, It might be reverted by package updates. Better create a copy to `/etc/systemd/system` and edit this copy according to your preferences. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458252/314876

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And most important information by this topic, for convertation standalone to cluster(replica set) this parameter in system service DO NOT NEED DELETE, but if you real need delete this string by your custom task, then use my instruction)